# Sixth and eighth moments of a complex Gaussian random vector

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expectation, means

Considering the random vector $\textbf{h} = [h_{1}, h_{2}, \ldots, h_{M}]^{T} \sim \mathcal{CN}(\textbf{0}_{M},d\textbf{I}_{M \times M})$, what would be the expectation of

$\mathbb{E}[\| \textbf{h} \|^{6}]$ and $\mathbb{E}[\| \textbf{h} \|^{8}]$ ?

Comment: @J.G., I've tried to expand like this: $(\sum_{m=1}^{M} |h_{m}|^{2} )^{4} = \sum_{m=1}^{M} \sum_{k=1}^{M} \sum_{j=1}^{M} \sum_{l=1}^{M} |h_{m}|^{2}  |h_{k}|^{2}  |h_{j}|^{2}  |h_{l}|^{2} $, however, I don't know how to proceed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: the following treatment assumes $d$ generalises the variance in a univariate $N(0,\,\sigma^2)$ distribution. I'm also not an expert on the complex Gaussian distribution, so I'll "flatten" the variable to a $2M$-dimensional real multivariate Gaussian. (This allows us to drop the $||$ signs around even powers.) There might be some powers-of-$2$ errors, but hopefully you can fix the sketch below.

Let $a=\frac{1}{2d}$, so unitarity is the condition $\int d^{2M}\mathbf{h}\exp -ah^2=(\pi/a)^{M}$. Differentiating both sides $k$ times with respect to $a$, and dividing by the original equation, gives $$\mathbf{E}h^{2k}=(M)^{(k)} a^{-k}=(M)^{(k)} (2d)^{k},$$where $(x)^{(k)}:=\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(x+i)$ is the rising Pochhammer symbol. This technique for evaluating even moments is well-known for the case $M=1/2$ [sic], say with $d=1$ for brevity. For example, if $H\sim N(0,\,1)$ then $$\mathbb{E}H^2=\frac{1}{2}2=1,\,\mathbb{E}H^4=\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{2}2^2=3,$$and similarly $\mathbb{E}H^6=15,\,\mathbb{E}H^8=105$. In theory, the $6$th & $8$th moments are respectively $8d^3 M(M+1)(M+2),\,16d^4 M(M+1)(M+2)(M+3)$.

Comment: From previous calculations (also confirmed via simulations) I know that $\mathbb{E}[\| \textbf{h} \|^{4}] = d^{2}M(M+1)$, however, applying your formula I find $\mathbb{E}[\| \textbf{h} \|^{4}] = 2d^{2}M(M+1)$. Where is this "2" coming from? Additionally, in the integral in your answer, why do you have the term $d^{2M}$ multiplying $\textbf{h}\exp{-ah^2}$? Thanks!

Comment: @FelipeAugustodeFigueiredo As I mentioned before, there are likely powers-of-2 errors in my complex-to-real switch. The $d^{2M}$ isn't a power of $d$, although I can understand that confusion given that there's a variable called $d$ in the problem! For an $n$-dimensional vector $\mathbf{x}$, $d^n\mathbf{x}:=\prod_{i=1}^n dx_i$ is an $n$-tuple integration operator.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your calculations, however, I think there is something wrong here: $\int d^{2M}\mathbf{h}\exp -ah^2=(\pi a)^{-M}$, shouldn't it be: $\int d^{2M}\mathbf{h}\exp -ah^2=(\frac{\pi}{a})^{M}$?

Comment: @FelipeAugustodeFigueiredo Sorry, yes; I'll fix that.

Comment: Last question, I was wondering about odd moments, would they be equal to 0?

Comment: @FelipeAugustodeFigueiredo Yes, by symmetry.